# PDF.js default spread setting

Tags: pdf.js

Basic question...is there a way to set a default setting for spread view in PDF.js viewer?

I want to be able to change the spread setting based on my layout, for example to 'no spreads' option but I can't find procedure for this in the official documentation or on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the solution and it wasn't so hard after all.

For anyone struggling with this problem, you need to open viewer.js and change "spreadModeOnLoad" (-1 is for the last browsers (or PDF file's) default state, 0 is for no spreads and 1 is for obligatory spreads).

The part of the code is located here:

```
function getDefaultPreferences() {
  if (!defaultPreferences) {
    defaultPreferences = Promise.resolve({
      "cursorToolOnLoad": 0,
      "defaultZoomValue": "",
      "disablePageLabels": false,
      "enablePermissions": false,
      "enablePrintAutoRotate": false,
      "enableWebGL": false,
      "externalLinkTarget": 0,
      "historyUpdateUrl": false,
      "ignoreDestinationZoom": false,
      "pdfBugEnabled": false,
      "renderer": "canvas",
      "renderInteractiveForms": true,
      "sidebarViewOnLoad": -1,
      "scrollModeOnLoad": -1,
      "spreadModeOnLoad": 1,
      "textLayerMode": 1,
      "useOnlyCssZoom": false,
      "viewOnLoad": 0,
      "disableAutoFetch": false,
      "disableFontFace": false,
      "disableRange": false,
      "disableStream": false
    });
  }

  return defaultPreferences;
}
```

Comment: If you need multiple options (one page with spreads and other without), just make two separate viewers (both html and js) and then re-link the viewer2.html with viewer2.js, voila :D